# How to install xcode 5 on OSX 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, osx-yosemite

I just got a new Macbook and its Yosemite. When I installed xcode, I just see xcode6 in app store. But all my ios programming books are for ios7 and they are using xcode5. I found xcode 6 has many difference from 5, so how could I install xcode5 under OSX 10.10 Yosemite?

Answer (score 2):

Download previous versions of Xcode from here (https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action)

You would need to login with your apple id and then search for the Xcode you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Often we need Xcode version for Brew installer, but if your MacOS is old and you dont find Xcode compatible . Use the command "brew doctor" and download that version from 
https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Answer (score 1):

You can download all the developer tools on https://developer.apple.com/downloads/.

(You must login before)